# eos-sharp api call gets failed

Tags: nodeos, rpc, api, c#

I am a beginner with **EOSIO**. I may make a mistake in code. I installed **eos-sharp** in the visual studio using the *NuGet package*. My code is as below:

```
using EosSharp;
using EosSharp.Core;
using EosSharp.Core.Providers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace eostest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Eos eos = new Eos(new EosConfigurator()
        {
            HttpEndpoint = "https://127.0.0.1:8888",
            ChainId = "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
            ExpireSeconds = 60,
            SignProvider = new DefaultSignProvider("myprivatekey")
        });

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getinfo();
        }

        public async void getinfo()
        {
            var result = await eos.GetInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Nodeos is running on the localhost. I confirmed by using *http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info* which shows output. When I run this program, nothing happens. 
After 1:40 minutes it throws an exception as below:

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   EosSharp.HttpHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage) in
>   HttpHelper.cs
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   EosSharp.HttpHandler.GetJsonAsync(string) in HttpHelper.cs
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   ... [Call Stack Truncated]

How would I confirm whether the parameters are correct and the chain is connected or not? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a minor change. My bad! I just changed

```
HttpEndpoint = "https://127.0.0.1:8888",
```

to

```
HttpEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
```

and it worked. Everything is running fine now.